# Why is there no error after calling a deleted objects member?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Shouldn't I get an error at line 8 of "main.cpp"?

- I am not using a destructor.
- I think it has something to do with the "const" keyword.

main.cpp:

```
#include "stack.hpp"
int main() {
    node* firstnode = new node(NULL, 5);
    std::cout << firstnode -> getvariable() << std::endl;
    node* secondnode = new node(NULL, 10);
    std::cout << secondnode -> getvariable() << std::endl;
    delete firstnode;
    std::cout << firstnode -> getvariable() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

stack.hpp:

```
#ifndef stack_hpp
#define stack_hpp
#include <iostream>
class node {
public:
    node(node* nextnode, int variablevalue);
    void setvariable(const int variablevalue);
    const int getvariable() const;
private:
    node* nextnodelink;
    int variable;
};
#endif
```

stack.cpp:

```
#include "stack.hpp"
node::node(node* nextnode, int variablevalue)
: nextnodelink(nextnode), variable(variablevalue) {
}

const int node::getvariable() const {
    return variable;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should get undefined behavior. It's not a promise to do anything, like reporting an error.

Comment: So it is deleted then, it's just g++. Thanks!

Comment: [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is _undefined_ – it can _appear_ to work, or it can set your computer on fire. Either way it's wrong.

Comment: One thing to remember about undefined behavior - it doesn't have to be consistent. Just because it works once doesn't mean it will work next time.

Comment: @ildjarn, That's ok. My fan will take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete an object, the memory that object occupies will be put back to be "available". So that computers run fast, the design of the "make it available" is such that it doesn't do very much other than add the freed object to a linked list or something like that. It doesn't, for example, fill it with nonsense so that it becomes unusable. The point with C++ is that it's fast - to make every `delete` fill the object will nonsense just to make sure you can't use it later would slow it down.

Of course, it may be that, if you make some other allocations, the contents of the object is indeed "bad". This is why it's "undefined". The standard doesn't say what will happen, and almost anything CAN happen. Computer catching fire is unlikely, but the C standard doesn't in itself have any wording to say "it must not cause computer to catch fire" or anything of that sort.

A good rule of thumb is that if you want to make your code safe, set the pointer to NULL after you deleted it. That way, your prgram will most likely crash when the pointer is being used.

For example:

```
delete firstnode;
firstnode = NULL;
std::cout << firstnode -> getvariable() << std::endl;
```

Now, your program should crash when you call "getvariable". It's not 100% sure to always do that. If you have a function that returns a constant for example, it may still "work".

Comment: I guess "this = NULL" would be useful in a destructor when I make one wouldn't it? Good answer, thanks.

Comment: No "this" has the same value but isn't the same as "firstnode" - that's like `void foo(int x) { x = 0; } ... y = 7; foo(y);` - it won't change the value of y. replace the name of the function to the destructor name, replace x with this, and y with firstnode, and it's the same thing.

Comment: Would it be possible to set the pointer to NULL in the destructor? Possibly using some sort of reference?

Comment: No, the way that the destructor works is that the "this" pointer is a hidden argument (like all other member functions), and you can't "make it a reference".

Comment: It would be nice if you could.

Comment: Yes, but also a tiny bit less efficient if you have to delete a large number of objects, which goes back to "C++ is designed to be as efficient a language as possible". It does allow you to do things that you shouldn't - because if it's a choice between "make it fast" or "make it safe", the choice is "fast".

Answer (score 0):

You're getting undefined behavior, which is (in this case) still working (probably) due to the reason you're just returning a single value.

`firstnode->getvariable()` in your case will only tell your CPU to get the value stored at `firstnode + x`, where x is simply an offset based on the structure of your class.

This is will most likely work without causing any immediate issues or errors as long as you're not trying to do something with that variable (or the pointer `firstnode`), e.g. interpreting it as a string or whatever, because `firstnode` will still point into valid memory, which just isn't allocated anymore (i.e. "don't use this").

It is however possible, that the compiler adds some overhead code for debug builds (not necessarily your compiler), that will cause an exception if you try this.

Comment: Well, quotes around "fine" for a reason. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an error, the generated code would need to keep track of what you've created and what you've deleted and check each and every time whether an operation is legal. That doesn't come for free, but incurs costs in both time and space. Therefore it's not done. C++ generally avoids introducing checks that would incur runtime overhead.

So it's your responsibility to not induce undefined behavior.